# To read the content of a file in C

Tags: c

I have a C code to read a txt file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    FILE *pf;
    int ii;
    int jj;   

    char *filename;
    printf("enter file name");
    scanf("%s",filename);        

    printf("%s",filename);

    pf = fopen("filename+.txt", "r");
    if(pf==Null)
    {
        printf("cant open");
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(pf,"%d,%d" ,&ii,&jj );
        printf("%d,%d\n" ,ii,jj);
    }
    fclose(pf);    

    return 0;
}
```

Still i get segmentation error.
The input txt file contains

> 2,3

I get segmentation fault(core dumped) when i run the program as ./readfile input.
What is going wrong here , how can i correct this?

Comment: You've got completely wrong main method signature

Comment: In fopen, the first parameter should be filename, no " and the other adjustments you type.As is, you would expect a segmentation error.

Comment: And as you have it now, your last paragraph doesn't describe how you'd use this program: instead, just type ./readfile if you compiled it under that name (no cmd line param).

Comment: @Rdvsm: And why have you just removed the source? What's the point?

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes here.

After calling `fopen()`, you should check if `pf` is `NULL`, because `fopen()` can fail.

You are trying to open the file of name `filename+.txt`. Shouldn't you be opening the file which the name was provided as parameter?

Also, the structure of `main()` should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, you cannot do whatever you want about this.

Check if `argc > 1`, in which case the program was started with parameters, and the file name should've been provided in `argv[1]`.

Update on comments: This is how your code should look like:

```
int main()
{
    char filename[512]; // reserve 512 bytes to receive the file name from input
    FILE *pf;
    int ii;
    int jj;   

    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    pf = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (pf)
    {
        fscanf(pf,"%d,%d", &ii, &jj);
        printf("%d,%d\n", ii, jj);
        fclose(pf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to open file name %s", filename);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also do this to get the filename from the parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *pf;
    int ii;
    int jj;   

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        pf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (pf)
        {
            fscanf(pf, "%d,%d", &ii, &jj);
            printf("%d,%d\n", ii, jj);
            fclose(pf);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Failed to open file name %s", argv[1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Insuficient parameters");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or even, if you don't want to pass the file extension:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *filename;
    FILE *pf;
    int ii;
    int jj;   

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        filename = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 5); // alloc necessary memory
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
        strcat(filename, ".txt");

        pf = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (pf)
        {
            fscanf(pf, "%d,%d", &ii, &jj);
            printf("%d,%d\n", ii, jj);
            fclose(pf);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Failed to open file name %s", filename);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Insuficient parameters");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the code as above.But i still get segmentation error

Comment: Yeah I see you changed your code, but now you are trying to read the file name to an unitialized pointer. You have to use `malloc()` to alloc memory space to receive the filename the user is about to type. And your `fopen()` is still trying to open the file which the name is literally `"filename+.txt"`. I suppose you have to change that too.

Answer (score 2):

`int main(char *)` is not a legal signature for `main` in C.  Only

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

are legal.  In your case, you will need the latter.

Comment: I have edited the code , but there still seems to give the same error

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct way to specify arguments to your program.  *ie* you can't do this:

```
int main(char *filename)
```

There should have been a compiler error when you compiled your program.  The correct definition is:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

Where `argv` is an array of strings.  Try doing this experiment:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) {
        printf( "arg %d is: \"%s\"\n", argv[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, write your program to use the correct argument list as above.

One other point to make is that you should test the return value of `fopen`.  If it is `NULL`, then you should NOT try to access the file (because it failed to open).

Comment: You are using an uninitialised pointer `filename`, and then trying to read into it.  A pointer needs to point at actual memory.  If you want memory to hold characters, declare are `char` array or allocate dynamically with `malloc`.  The point of this answer was to help you get a value from the command line, not try something completely different.